# C# Socket.Select and writes

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to write a tcp server which can handle multiple clients in one thread. I really want to stick to exactly one thread, even no hidden C# async threads, so I want to use `Socket.Select` instead of using the asynchronous receive/send methods.

While reading the documentation of `Select`, I was wondering how select tells me how many bytes it can send without blocking. Its documentation tells:

> If you already have a connection established, writability means that
>   all send operations will succeed without blocking.

So according to the documentation, it seems that I can issue a huge send operation and it will succeed without blocking. But how does this work if I put in a send operation of let's say 100 megabytes. Surely, the socket's write buffer cannot contain that much data, so the socket must either block or write only a small portion of the data. What does the socket do here?

Comment: `I really want to stick to exactly one thread, even no hidden C# async threads` **=>** [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: @Eser: Then simply forget my motivation paragraph, but still I am interested in the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using non-blocking socket [`Send`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4t14718h(v=vs.110).aspx) will only send the bytes it can buffer.  It's return value will be the number of bytes that it actually sent.

Straight from the documentation for Send:

> In nonblocking mode, Send may complete successfully even if it sends
>   less than the number of bytes you request. It is your application's
>   responsibility to keep track of the number of bytes sent and to retry
>   the operation until the application sends the requested number of
>   bytes.

Comment: So using `Select` simply only makes sense when all used sockets are set to non-blocking mode, correct?

Comment: `Select` will work fine with blocking sockets, but yeah it isn't normally done.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want many threads, I think this project will be helpful:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488668/Csharp-NET-TCP-Server

Author presents solution which allows multiple clients on one TCP server socket with 2 threads, regardless of the number of connected clients.

Hope it helps!

---

Unless you want to do everything in just single thread, including application logic, then... don't do this :)

Fun fact:
In Android (since API level 11) you can't create application with network operations in main thread because application will crash right away after start with NetworkOnMainThreadException. I think this shows gravity of the situation ;)